# Minimum priority queue with objects

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I'm trying to create a minimum priority queue of type `Job` using the STL in C++. I have the following code:

```
class Job
{
public:
    int IOtime;
};

struct grThan
{
    bool operator()(const Job& l, const Job& r) const
    {  
        return l.IOtime > r.IOtime;  
    }  
};
```

I am declaring the queue `std::priority_queue<Job, vector<Job>, grThan> IO;`

I get the following error:

`bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const Job'`

Comment: Compiled well with MSVC2013.  Did you compile with gcc ?  With c++11 option ?

Comment: Where and how does `std::string` come into the picture? It's absent from the code you've shown, but the error message refers to it. I suggest you post a small complete example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// stackoverflow_26691997.cpp (cX) 2015 adolfo.dimare@gmail.com
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691997/

#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Job {
public:
    int IOtime;
};

struct grThan {
    bool operator()(const Job& l, const Job& r) const {
        return l.IOtime > r.IOtime;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<Job, std::vector<Job>, grThan> IO;
}
```